# Qt не запускает проекты

Tags: c++, qt

Модуль QML не содержит информации об элементах содержащихся в расширении

Путь к модулю: E:/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/qml
См. раздел «Using QML Modules with Plugins» документации.

Не удалось загрузить типы из модуля QML.
Ошибки:
«E:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\mingw491_32\bin\qmlplugindump.exe» возвратила код завершения: 3.
Аргументы: --builtins
QQmlComponent: Component is not ready
file:///loadqtquick2.qml:1:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick": Plugin verification data mismatch in 'E:/Qt/Qt5.4.0/5.4/mingw491_32/qml/QtQuick.2/qtquick2plugin.dll'

Переустанавливал, бесполезно

Запускается L:\QTkiuy\5\debug\5.exe...
SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)
Программа неожиданно завершилась.
L:\QTkiuy\5\debug\5.exe завершился крахом

Comment: Пробовал другие версии Qt?

Comment: мне рекомендовали именно эту, так как она с настроенным компилятором...

Comment: Для проверки чисто. Что бы локализовать проблему.

Comment: уже пробую, отпишусь по окончании

Comment: работает, спасибо! просто действовал по указаниям преподавателя, боялся самодеятельности, т.к. раньше не имел дела с qt